# How to get a list of available files using wget or curl?

Tags: bash, curl, terminal, wget

I'd like to know if it's possible to do an `ls` of a URL, so I can see what *.js files are available in a website, for example. Something like:

```
wget --list-files -A.js stackoverflow.com
```

and get

```
ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
js/full.js
js/stub.js
...
```

Comment: See the following for a work-around: http://superuser.com/questions/642555/view-all-files-in-a-websites-directory

Comment: @interestedparty333's tip is a useful one, but I'm not sure that `lftp` is going to be digging inside HTML documents to pull out all the `<link rel="stylesheet">`, though. How you define "what […] files are available in a website" makes a pretty big difference for the approach you use. If you are actually talking about parsing HTML, look into [`xidel`](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html), [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), [`pup`](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), or similar.

Comment: _e.g._, `curl https://stackoverflow.com | pup 'link[rel="stylesheet"] attr{href}'`, which sort of does what you're asking for, but non-recursively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do the equivalent of an `ls` unless the server provides such listings itself. You could however retrieve `index.html` and then check for includes, e.g. something like

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com | grep "type=.\?text/javascript.\?"
```

Note that this relies on the HTML being formatted in a certain way -- in this case with the includes on individual lines for example. If you want to do this properly, I'd recommend parsing the HTML and extracting the javascript includes that way.

Comment: Thanks for making clear the distinction between a list of files served via HTTP (à la Apache [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) pages) and actually _parsing_ the HTML to get a list of other resources referenced within the page. I still get confused by this, too. Furthermore, in the year 2022, there are good tools for the latter, which let you reliably pull out `<a>`s and `<link rel="stylesheet">`s with XPath or CSS selectors instead of regexes, as noted above.

Answer (score 7):

Let's consider this open directory (http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/) as the object of our experimentation. This directory belongs to [the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](https://ctan.org/), so don't be too worried about downloading malicious files.

Now, let's suppose that we want to list all files whose extension is `pdf`. We can do so by executing the following command.

The command shown below will save the output of `wget` in the file `main.log`. Because `wget` send a request for each file and it prints some information about the request, we can then `grep` the output to get a list of files which belong to the specified directory.

```
wget \
  --accept '*.pdf' \
  --reject-regex '/\?C=[A-Z];O=[A-Z]$' \
  --execute robots=off \
  --recursive \
  --level=0 \
  --no-parent \
  --spider \
  'http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/' 2>&1 | tee main.log
```

Now, we can list the files whose extension is `pdf` by using `grep`.

```
grep '^--' main.log
```

```
--2020-11-23 10:39:46--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/
--2020-11-23 10:39:47--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/
--2020-11-23 10:39:47--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/amsbooka.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:47--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:47--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/amsdtx.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:47--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/amsmidx.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:48--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:48--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/thmtest.pdf
--2020-11-23 10:39:48--  http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/required/amscls/doc/upref.pdf
```

Note that we could also get the list of all files in the directory and then execute `grep` on the output of the command. However, doing this would have taken more time since apparently a request is sent for each file. By using the `--accept`, we can make `wget` send a request for only those files in which we are interested in.

Last but not least, the sizes of the files are saved in the file `main.log`, so you can check that information in that file.

Comment: The `--reject-regex '/\?C=[A-Z];O=[A-Z]$'` part is a good tip for sites served up by Apache's [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html). Thanks!

Comment: Why `--level=0`? The man page specifies this to mean infinite recursion.